# cloning only a specific item in a list using .clone() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add only select items of a list to a new list. So for example, I only wish to add banana to my second list, the following code in my function adds all the items in coll-selected-list to coll-grouped-list. How may I only make a clone of a specific item. Any tips would be great.

jQuery:

```
$("#coll-selected-list li").clone().appendTo("#coll-grouped-list");
```

Markup:

```
<ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue sort-drop ui-sortable">
      <li class="sorted">apple</li>
      <li class="sorted">pear</li>
      <li class="sorted">banana</li>
      <li class="sorted">grape</li>
      <li class="sorted">guava</li>
</ul>

<ul id="coll-grouped-list">
</ul>
```

Comment: don't forget to mark a correct answer if you're happy with one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("#coll-selected-list li:contains('banana')").clone().appendTo("#coll-grouped-list");
```

Note that the string you pass to `:contains` is case sensitive.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/LQ3ax/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom data attribute and value to the items you want to clone and then only target items with that data attribute and value.

**e.g.**

```
<ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue sort-drop ui-sortable">
      <li class="sorted">apple</li>
      <li class="sorted">pear</li>
      <li class="sorted" data-action="clone">banana</li>
      <li class="sorted">grape</li>
      <li class="sorted">guava</li>
</ul>

<ul id="coll-grouped-list">
</ul>

$('#coll-selected-list li[data-action="clone"]').clone().appendTo("#coll-grouped-list");
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/QXEdn/

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to elements which you want to clone e.g.:

```
<ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue sort-drop ui-sortable">
      <li class="sorted">apple</li>
      <li class="sorted">pear</li>
      <li class="sorted clone">banana</li>
      <li class="sorted">grape</li>
      <li class="sorted">guava</li>
</ul>

<ul id="coll-grouped-list">
</ul>

// get elements with clone class
$('#coll-selected-list li.clone]').clone().appendTo("#coll-grouped-list");
```

If you want to clone elements based on index you can use [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
// clone li containing bannana
$('#coll-selected-list li:eq(2)]').clone().appendTo("#coll-grouped-list");
```